# Android Firebase Show current Loged in user details

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to show the details of the current user logged in. I have tryed a few methods to try and solve this but all it seems to return is null. My user firebase database is :

[image: Database]

Where am i going wrong ?

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


Button mBeerButton;
Button mBeerButtonTwo;
Button mBeerButtonThree;
Button mBeerButtonFour;
Button mSignOutButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);


    String mUserID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String mUsername = dataSnapshot.child("mUserName").getValue().toString();
            Toast.makeText(homeScreen.this,"User name is "+ mUsername,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your JSON structure. You are skipping one of the nodes. Change it as follows:

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String mUsername = dataSnapshot.child("JoBlogsUser").child("mUserName").getValue().toString();
            Toast.makeText(homeScreen.this,"User name is "+ mUsername,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Yunus answer (which works fine if you know the key of the node you want to show), here's how you can get all nodes under `Users` and then iterate over the child nodes:

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String mUsername = userSnapshot.child("mUserName").getValue(String.class);
            Toast.makeText(homeScreen.this,"User name is "+ mUsername,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});
```